# Language switcher using get language variable instead of prefix in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, blocks, i18n-l10n

In Drupal 8 setting  url with path prefix for language detection, works fine. But when I include the language switcher block included with Drupal, the links instead of using the language prefix, show links using the variable language in the url.

How can I make the language switcher make use of the language prefix instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugins you enable in the language detection configuration also contain the methods to build outbound paths and the language switcher links. The plugin for *Url* adds prefixes, not query strings. Others do, for example *Session* for anonymous users, so you probably have enabled a second detection method.

Comment: Thanks @4k4 I have just discovered the problem was caused because Session was enabled also as detection method.